# Syntax error in MySQL Join Query

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm getting a syntax error in MySQL query. Is MySQL and SQL server work differently? Can anyone suggest, what is wrong and where ?

```
select b.component, d.matter, d.bug, d.timestamp,  d.os 
from bugs.profiles p, ops_reports.BPR_TAG_DATA d
left join (Select * from bugs where product='test') b 
on d.bug=b.bug_id
where d.tagid = 6
and timestamp between "2014-04-21" and "2014-04-24"
and login_name like 'test'
and p.userid = d.user
```

**Error Message**      24/04/2014 23:14:10        0:00:00.037         MySQL Database Error: You have an error in your SQL syntax.  Check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'Select * from bugs where product='Conversions') as b 
on (d.bu               1              0

Comment: Do not mix implicit (comma-) join and explicit join syntax. In fact do not use comma-join syntax at all

Comment: Strawberry, Can you please describe little more or put your suggested query here, if possible

Comment: The **error message** appears to be for some SQL text that is **different** from the SQL text provided. The inline view (aliased as b) isn't necessary, and ditch the old-school comma syntax for the join operation. Use the `JOIN` keyword in place of the comma, and relocate join predicates from the WHERE clause to an appropriate ON clause. Also, best practice is to qualify *all* column references. (e.g. `and b.timestamp BETWEEN`... easier for the reader to decipher AND avoids query breaking with "ambiguous column" error when column of the same name later added to another table

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not mix implicit and explicit joins.  A simple rule:  just don't use commas in the `from` clause.

```
select b.component, d.matter, d.bug, d.timestamp, d.os 
from ops_reports.BPR_TAG_DATA d left join
     bugs b
     on b.product = 'test' and d.bug = b.bug_id left join
     bugs.profiles p
     on p.userid = d.user
where d.tagid = 6 and
      timestamp between '2014-04-21' and '2014-04-24' and
      login_name like 'test';
```

I also removed the subquery, moving the condition to the `on` clause.  This makes the query more efficient.  And changed the delimiters for the date constants to single quotes.  Using double quotes for strings can lead to confusion.

EDIT:

All this said, the query in the question *looks* like it is syntactically correct.  I notice that the error message does not refer to this exact query.  The query has `product='test') b` and the error message has `product='Conversions') as b`.  Perhaps there are other differences as well.

Comment: Thanks Gordon, the test was replaced, as i don't wanted to put the actual value. Sorry :) for confusion. It's working now.